# Question on improving perfomance of C# DotNetty tcp server

Tags: c#, netty, dotnetty

I am experiencing an issue with delayed message sending when attempting to write to a TCP channel from a separate UDP listener thread in my application. The setup involves a DotNetty TCP server and a UDP listener running on different threads. The UDP listener is designed to receive messages and then send them through the TCP channel.

- The TCP server is set up using the ServerBootstrap class.
- Upon receiving a message on the UDP socket, I use the following method to write to the TCP channel:

```
context.Channel.EventLoop.Execute(() =>
{
    context.WriteAndFlushAsync(Unpooled.WrappedBuffer(recvBuffer));
});
```

- Expected Behavior: The messages should be sent to the TCP channel without significant delay.
- Actual Behavior: The messages are experiencing delays, sometimes being sent only once every few seconds and by batches, which is much slower than expected.

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- Ensured that WriteAndFlushAsync is called within the channel's event loop using Execute.
- Checked for blocking operations and system resource constraints.

I am trying to send live audio, so 5-10 seconds delay, which I am experiencing are not acceptable. I know that when writing is done on other thread than eventloop's, it is scheduled and not done immediately. Is there a way to make something here?

Here is the way I boostrap the server.

```
var acceptorGroup = new MultithreadEventLoopGroup(1);
var workerGroup = new MultithreadEventLoopGroup();

var bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
    .Group(acceptorGroup, workerGroup)
    .Channel<TcpServerSocketChannel>()
    .ChildHandler(new ActionChannelInitializer<ISocketChannel>(channel =>
    {
        var handler = new ChannelHandler(
            _loggerFactory,
            _listenerOptions.DeviceRegistry,
            _listenerOptions.CallHostOptions,
            _messageFactory);

        channel.Pipeline.AddLast(handler);
    }))
    .ChildOption(ChannelOption.TcpNodelay, true);
```

Thank you for your time and help!

**UPD:**
Here are more details on my setup as requested by one of the commenters, so it is more clear what is going on.

Basically, I have ffmpeg process that constantly sends data to udp socket mentioned above: "ffmpeg -re -i input.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 -c:a pcm_alaw -f alaw udp://127.0.0.1:50343".

The udp socket recieves the data in real-time, with no delays, then makes some processing and calls WriteAndFlushAsync on the context object of type IChannelHandlerContext. This all happends in a separate thread, not in the EventLoop or ChannelHandler thread.

The way I measure perfomance is by comparing it with the case when I send data inside ChannelHandler thread. Basically when I'm writing to the channel it almost immediately appears in the WireShark, but when the writing is done in the udp socket it takes some time before I see the packets in the WireShark, also packets are sent in batches (3-4).

I have poor knowledge of netty or dotnetty, as far as I understand, the latency is due to additional overhead of thread syncronizatio and queing in eventloop. Maybe there is something can be done in the server configuration to fix that. Or maybe you can suggested another workaround to to solve bad setup?

Comment: I think to get a good answer to this it needs more details about what someone would have to do to reproduce your issue and details about how you measured the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've left some additional information about my setup, hope it will help to understand the problem more clear.